# How can i check whether an element can host Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

Elements that allow Shadow DOM are specified here:
https://docs.w3cub.com/dom/element/attachshadow/

How can i validate if an element supports Shadow DOM or not ?

```
if (myElement.attachShadow) {
    ...
}
```

does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and catch if unsupported.

```
try {
   let shadowRoot = elem.attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
   shadowRoot.innerHTML = ...;
   return true;
} catch( err ) {
   return false;
}
```

You could also turn this into a helper, but if you need to use it several times, it might then be a good idea to store the results after checking each element.

```js
function canAttachShadow( elem ) {
  try {
    elem.cloneNode().attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
    return true;
  }
  catch( err ) {
    return false;
  }
}
  
console.log( "a", canAttachShadow( document.createElement( "a" ) ) );
console.log( "article", canAttachShadow( document.createElement( "article" ) ) );
```

If you really wish, you could also use the specs algorithm, which is a combination of
[valid-custom-element-name](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name) and
the [white list](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-attachshadow) in your article (i.e today, *"article", "aside",
"blockquote", "body", "div", "footer", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "header", "main", "nav", "p", "section", or
"span"*), however this white list may change in the future, so any code using it would need to get updated along with
the specs.

Comment: Ah yes, checking for the error is probably the best approach. I edited you answer a bit, see if you think it looks ok - else just roll back.

Comment: @swelet no problem about the edit on the ground, but be careful not to break the code in it next time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it like this:

```
if (document.myElement.createShadowRoot || document.myElement.attachShadow) {
    // support shadow DOM
} else {
    // not support
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but apart from adding a check for (the now deprecated) .createShadowRoot I cannot see how this differs from what I tried before. Also, as an aside, this does not work with Typescript which does not know about .createShadowRoot. +1 one for thinking about older browsers though.